# google not recognizing my api key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-authentication

I have created a google developers account. I have created a project in there. I have enabled the JavaScript maps API for the project, and I have created a **browser** key for it, and I have limited the usage of it to the domain of my web site that people will be viewing. When I go to do an autocomplete call on a form field in my page, I get the following error back in the response.

```
"This service requires an API key.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key"
```

So I read the page, and that's how and why I set everything up previously mentioned. But it still will not work, and I just can't figure out why.

What subtlety am I missing?

BTW, this is with Chrome if that means anything, haven't bothered with other browsers

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=us" key="xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted this, I DID do my homeworok and I read the proper articles. Is it so bad when someone just doesn't see a small mistake they are making? What ever happened to the favor of a second pair of eyes? This was NOT due to a lack of effort and research, but thanks for the down vote anyway, and now there's nothing I can do about it now because of your "opinion"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting an HTML attribute.  The key should instead be included in the src URL according to the link you posted.

Straight from their example:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notice the location of "YOUR_API_KEY" in the URL.  Your best bet when dealing with APIs like this is to look for examples and follow them as closely as you can, trying to understand them.  Then modify them to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just needed a second pair of eyes. Thank you. Been doing this too long today. I'll mark it answered.